# como agregar datos a un array con bucle for? javascript

Tags: javascript, arraylist, datos

estoy recien iniciando en programacion y cuando practico para agregar datos a un array con bucle for en lugar de tener los datos, me agrega a my array nuevos array con los datos.

```js
let dato = []

for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    dato.push(i);
    console.log(dato)
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues ya lo hiciste, solo tendrías que mover el `console.log()` fuera del ciclo `for` para que veas el resultado:

```js
let dato = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  dato.push(i);
}

console.log(dato);
```

Comment: ahi mefunciono!! tenias razon el console.log tenia que salir del for!! muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Console log te imprime en consola lo que tú le pidas que te imprima al momento de el tiempo de ejecución, en tu código, tú estás pidiendo imprimir dato (que es tu arreglo) en cada push que le agregas, si lo que esperabas era imprimir el valor, e imprimir el arreglo al final; quizá buscas más algo como esto

```js
let dato = []

for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    dato.push(i);
    console.log(i)
}

    console.log(dato)
```